# Multiple GET's in Web API calling wrong action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have a `Web API`, that looks like the following...

```
public class LeaguesController : ApiController
{
    //api/Leagues/active/1
    //api/Leagues/complete/1
    //api/Leagues/both/1
    [GET("api/Leagues/{type}/{id}")]
    public List<Competition> Get([FromUri]int id, 
                                [FromUri]CompetitionManager.MiniLeagueType type)
    {
        return CompetitionManager.GetUsersMiniLeagues(id, true, type);
    }

    //api/Leagues/GetMiniLeagueTable/3
    [GET("api/Leagues/GetMiniLeagueTable/{id}")]
    public List<SportTableRow> GetMiniLeagueTable([FromUri]int id)
    {
        return SportManager.GetMiniLeagueTable("", id).TableRows;
    }
}
```

When I call the first method `Get`, this works fine.
When I use fiddler or Chrome REST Client to call the second method `GetMiniLeagueTable`, I am getting the following error:

> { Message: "The request is invalid." MessageDetail: "The parameters
>   dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'type' of non-nullable
>   type 'CompetitionManager+MiniLeagueType' for method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Competition] Get(Int32,
>   MiniLeagueType)' in 'LeaguesController'. An optional parameter must be
>   a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter." }

I am using [`AttributeRouting`](http://attributerouting.net/) to decorate the methods, but this doesn't seem to work.  It was working fine before I introduced `MiniLeagueType`.

Has anyone come across this issue, or can you point me to where I am going wrong?

Comment: how do you call it. there is something shouldnt be null passes as null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the cause is this url : `api/Leagues/GetMiniLeagueTable/3`. This url matches both routes, as it can be interpreted as such :  `api/Leagues?type=GetMiniLeagueTable&id=3`. But it cannot convert `GetMiniLeagueTable` as a `CompetitionManager.MiniLeagueType` value, so it raises an error.

You should make more specific routes, for example `api/Leagues/GetCompetitions/{type}/{id}`, in order to prevent url matching 2 or more different routes.

Another possibility is to invert your action orders, as it will check first action's route before going for the next one if the url doesn't match.

Comment: I didn't know that inverting the actions would do this, but it makes sense now...this has worked!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the url: /api/Leagues/GetMiniLeagueTable/3 would match both routes.

Assuming it matches the first route, it would then be unable to convert GetMiniLeagueTable to CompetitionManager.MiniLeagueType unless that was a valid enum value.

You second route probably needs to be tested first, and only if that fails to match the url, try the second.

Not having used attributerouting myself (though I have used the similar attribute routing in the latest web api) I'm guessing the [ActionPrecedence](http://attributerouting.net/#route-precedence) will help.

Try

```
[GET("api/Leagues/{type}/{id}", ActionPrecedence = 2)]
```

And

```
[GET("api/Leagues/GetMiniLeagueTable/{id}", ActionPrecedence = 1)]
```