# How does ASP.net web API determine which function to call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My ASP.NET web api has two functions : one which returns a list of all products and another which returns a list depending on a condition.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    List<Product> lst = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product(){ Id = 1, Name = "a Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product(){Id = 2, Name = "b Soup", Category = "stat", Price = 4 },
        new Product(){ Id = 3, Name = "c Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }
     };

     public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
     {
         return lst;
     }

     public List<Product> GetProducts(int k)
     {
         return lst.Where(p => p.Price == k).ToList();
     }
}

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I am using a GET method from jQuery as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getProducts() {
        $.getJSON("api/products/1",
            function (data) {
                debugger;
            });
    }
    $(document).ready(getProducts);
</script>
```

This function invokes the first function which is GetAllProducts even if I invoke it by calling

```
"api/products/1"
```

My question is how does it determine which function to call when invoking from the client?

Comment: Did you check your `RouteConfig.cs` file?

Comment: Hi Robert, just updated the routeconfig

Comment: And if you put `console.log(data);` instead of debugger and check the response?

Comment: I get 3 objects instead of one

Comment: According to the default route setting.. you should have 4 methods (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE). If you want to call your own methods, you need to specify the custom routes in route.config file.

Comment: If you rename the variable `k` of `GetProducts(int k)` into `id`, `GetProducts(int id)`, the `MapRoute` should be able to map the `Id` to the `Id` of the `ProductsController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of Web API, you could look at [*Attribute Routing*](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).  This will allow you to decorate the methods with a relevant pattern.

```
 [Route("products/getAll")]
 public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
 {
     return lst;
 }

 [Route("products/getByPrice/{price}")]
 public List<Product> GetProducts(int price)
 {
     return lst.Where(p => p.Price == price).ToList();
 }
```

Above is just an example, so you select what suits your needs.  If you're using an **old version**, you can get the [*AttributeRouting library here*](http://attributerouting.net/).

You also have an `ActionPresedence`, see [*my question here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965409/multiple-gets-in-web-api-calling-wrong-action).

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of `Get` methods in this controller. Web API is Restful, then when you call the server It will return the first Method named as `Get`, in your case **GetAllProducts**. You can call directly the other method:

```
function getProducts() {
    $.getJSON("api/products/GetProducts/1",
        function (data) {
            debugger;
        });
}
```

If you are using WebAPI v2.0, you can use atributte route to set the default route for every method in the controller:

```
[Route("api/products/{k}")]
public List<Product> GetProducts(int k)
{
    return lst.Where(p => p.Price == k).ToList();
}
```

Then you can call "api/products/1".

- [WebAPI Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

The Web API framework uses a routing table defined in the WebApiConfig.cs file, which is placed in the App_Start directory.

The Visual Studio project template for Web API creates a default route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When the Web API receives an HTTP request, it tries to match the URI against one of the route templates in the routing table.

If no route matches, the client receives a 404 error. For example, the following URIs match the default route:

```
/api/contacts
/api/contacts/1
/api/products/gizmo1
```

However, the following URI does not match, because it lacks the "api" segment:

```
/contacts/1
```

In your case, you have a controller named Products and two Get Methods. That matches the convention and the Web Api uses the first one.