# Questions on WebAPI REST API design (tabled data & filter view)

Tags: asp.net, rest

I am new to RESTful API design, now I encountered a simple question about how to design my API.

Let's say a company is running a world-wide service, I want to generate report to show to CEO that the trends of our service, how many customers are using our service.

The report will show 3 tables on UI:

Table 1: World-wide total customers count per week, it has 2 columns:

`WeekNo., TotalCustomersCount`

Table 2: Total customers per geo-region, it has 3 columns:

`Region, WeekNo. TotalCustomersCount`

Table 3: Total customers per service type, it has 3 columns too:

`ServiceType, WeekNo. TotalCustomersCount`

My question is, how should I design my API? I don't want to treat table 1, 2 and 3 are different resources because obviously all of those tables are filtered views on the same database table.

==================================================================================

One of my thought is to design the API in this way, but I am not sure if this is the right way:

First, treat table 1 as resource;

Then, define the return result entity of ~/api/totalaccounts:

```
public class PivotedTotalCustomers
{
    public string Pivot {get;set;} //if empty or null, means no pivot, which is table 1.
    public uint WeekNo {get; set;}
    public uint TotalCustomersCount {get;set;}
}
```

At last, API template:

`/api/{controller}/{pivot},`pivot is optional, so API looks like:

```
~/api/totalcustomers/
~/api/totalcustomers/region
~/api/totalcustomers/servicetype
```

And method in controller:

```
public IQueryable<PivotedTotalCustomers> GetAllCustomers();
public IQueryable<PivotedTotalCustomers> GetPivotedAllCustomers(string pivot);
```

Comment: Do they all return the same *Data Type* as in the same collection?

Comment: @christiandev Yes, please refer to my supplement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest version, 2.x, then you can use a Route Attribute as seen below:

```
[Route("api/getallcustomers")]
public IQueryable<PivotedTotalCustomers> GetAllCustomers();
```

You can also set the order on the Route, take a look at an old question of mine [Multiple GET's in Web API calling wrong action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965409/multiple-gets-in-web-api-calling-wrong-action).

However, if you're using an older version of the Web API, then you'll need to use a third party library, [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) (which MS have actually implemented in the latest version).  My question from above will help further with attribute routing.

You can also use configuration Routing, which you can see in this article [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Thanks @christiandev . Actually my question is not so specific on webapi routing, I do want to ask in this case, what is the guideline of practise to design a RESTful API, what could be treated as resource? Should I create 3 resources and 3 controllers for each table, or use one resource + query params?

Comment: Since the underlying resource is the same, just create one IMO